# How to prevent shell command interrupt python script

Tags: python, subprocess

Currently I cannot import any 3rd party libraries such as paramiko which is used to handle SSH things.
I cannot handle one scenario while testing ssh connection.

Having code:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "user@server1", "echo", "123"])
```

I'm successfully retrieving output from this command because I have setup the ssh keys.
While trying connect to unknown server I receive "non-zero exit status 255" and I know how to handle this.

The problem is where I did not setup ssh keys and the server is known.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "user@server2", "echo", "123"])
```

I receive shell output:

```
user@server2's password:
```

Like I would normally try to connect through ssh without ssh key.
I've tried:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "user@server2", "echo", "123"], input=b"123")
result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "user@server2", "echo", "123"], stdin=b"123")
```

and only solution to this is make ssh command force to not ask for password

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "obatchmode=yes", "user@server2", "echo", "123"])
```

But I would like to know how to handle subprocess.check_output/run command in such cases where I cannot configure command not to ask for password. Like this code of block:

```
if subprocess.check_output IS ASKING FOR INPUT:
     DONT_WORRY_GO_AHEAD
```

Comment: you could connect with `user:password@server`

Comment: I know how ssh works - the question is how to check if executed script from shell is asking for input - I want to handle that